# Checking Presence of Same Value Across Multiple Variables

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for rows that contain any of multiple variables in a data.table. my current code works, but is a bit messy:

```
#dt contains several columns, foo1, foo2, foo3, etc that have the same possible values

#Values I am searching for
bar <- ("a","b","c")

#current method
dt[foo1 %in% bar| foo2 %in% bar | foo3 %in% bar ...]
```

This method works, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may also use

```
dt[dt[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%chin%`, bar))]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lapply` with `.SD` and `Reduce` -

```
library(data.table)

dt[, .SD[Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, bar))]]
```